# Adjust display settings from command line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, automation, external-display

The external monitor on my laptop doesn't position the image correctly. I would like to write a script that will adjust the H-position when executed.

Is something like this possible? I am a programmer so I'm not afraid of getting technical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the brilliant, free utility Display Changer from 12noon.
This has various switches to allow you to control resolution, position, offset etc of multiple monitors.

I have used this, and its predecessor ResChange with great success, and created one line batch files for common configurations so I could use shortcuts to quickly access them (eg laptop open + external monitor on customer site, two LCD screens via docking station when back at base).

http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm

I just re-read your question. If the problem is actually the position of the image on the monitor, try adjusting the refresh rate (something else you can do with Display Changer), as sometimes this fixes the problem, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, the problem is the position of the image on the monitor. I checked into changing the refresh rate like you suggested but the monitor doesn't support anything above 60 hertz. When I attempt to use 75 or 80 it just tells me it is out of range.